# 'npm start' throwing many 'Cannot find module' errors after cloning react-native project from linux to Mac

Tags: node.js, react-native

I have a react-native project that was started on a machine running Ubuntu. Recently I was switched to a MacBook Pro, and I cloned the project to it.

After installing the necessary dependencies (everything found in the directions [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html)) and running npm install inside my project folder, I try to run react-native run-android and I get the error `Cannot find module 'destroy'`. If I run `npm i -S destroy` and then `react-native run-android` again I get another error `Cannot find module 'range-parser'`. Again I npm install and run the project, but this happens several more times before I can run my project. I did not have these packages in the project before, and other projects I start on a Mac do not have these. Why am I incurring these errors? I have tried deleting node_modules and running `npm install` several times. I have uninstalled and reinstalled node. I have deleted the project locally and tried cloning again. A fresh clone and install on old machine works perfectly.

NPM Version 
 - Ubuntu 5.0.4 
 - Mac 5.0.3

Node Version 
 - Ubuntu 4.2.6
 - Mac 8.1.4

package.json

```
{
  "name": "MyProject",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest",
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "evil-icons": "^1.9.0",
    "firebase": "^4.1.3",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "react": "^16.0.0-alpha.13",
    "react-native": "^0.44.3",
    "react-native-clean-project": "^1.0.4",
    "react-native-config": "^0.4.2",
    "react-native-datepicker": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-device-info": "^0.10.2",
    "react-native-fcm": "^7.1.0",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.2.0",
    "react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.11",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.5",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-persist": "^4.8.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "20.0.3",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "1.9.2",
    "jest": "20.0.4",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0-alpha.6"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Here is everything I must install before being able to run my project:
destroy, hosted-git-info, is-builtin-module, range-parser, validate-npm-package-license

Comment: Basic troubleshooting, 1) have you tried a fresh install of the cloned project on your original Ubuntu machine, 2) how about on a new Ubuntu install (in a VM for example), 3) you should also post your NPM versions for both Ubuntu and macOS as well as your `package.json` for people to take a look over your dependencies.

Comment: versions added to original post and a fresh clone and install on old machine worked perfectly fine

Comment: Sounds like you are running into peer dependencies here. Starting from a particular version of Node these are no longer installed automatically. When you run npm install you may be getting warnings in the output that state that specific dependencies are missing and you need to install them

Comment: I don't see any warnings when doing npm install. I'm not even sure if this is an error. Just confused why these modules are suddenly being required. I listed the modules out at the bottom of the original post. Not sure if that helps identify any issue